# Bokeh: plotting a large data set

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to construct a graph that is very similar to the range_tool.py example

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/range_tool.html

Instead of using date time data, I have two lists each one is over 40,000 data points long.

Example lists:

`b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
phred = [17, 16, 6, 15, 6, 7, 6, 7, 9, 11, 16, 13, 9, 11, 12, 13, 6, 12, 13, 7]`

I want to plot b vs p and get the same image visualization as in the above link. 
The goal is to see the distribution of phred over b. 
The below code returns a graph but I want to better visualize the variability in phred over b and I am unsure about what settings to tweek so it looks more like the above example.

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(plot_height=300, plot_width=800, tools="", toolbar_location=None, x_range=(0, 50000))

p.line(b, phred)
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'phred score'

select = figure(plot_height=150, plot_width=800, y_range=p.y_range, y_axis_type=None, tools="", toolbar_location=None)

range_rool = RangeTool(x_range=p.x_range)
range_rool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_rool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.line(b, phred)
select.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_rool)
select.toolbar.active_multi = range_rool

show(column(p, select))
```

Here is my graph

[bokeh plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEeJO.png)

Comment: There is a missing closing ")" in line 1.

Comment: right! Thanks. That was edited.

Answer (score 1):

You are using "p" as name for the figure and one of your data lists!

You have to pass the list objects, not their names as strings.

Try:

```
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
c = [17, 16, 6, 15, 6, 7, 6, 7, 9, 11, 16, 13, 9, 11, 12, 13, 6, 12, 13, 7]
p.line(b, c)
```

Comment: great! That worked. The example had the list objects in quotes.

Comment: @LauraFisch The example uses a `ColumnDataSource`, which expects strings to indicate which columns to use. These strings were provided as kwargs in the example as `dict(date=dates, close=AAPL['adj_close'])` which is perfectly valid, but imo a little harder to read / understand that they get cast to strings.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around I found out the simple fix to better see the data was in line 1

setting the plot's first x_range to a smaller number
`x_range=(0, 2000)`

This setting improves the plot 
[improved bokeh plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4KHY.png)

If anyone has any suggestions on how to view such variable data please share

Comment: Honestly looking at the time series data just looks like noise. If you zoom in much further you might find some periodicity to it, but the data scientist in me sees that graph and just sees a single value plus a noise signal. Another alternative could be to use some sort of smoothing filter to get rid of the high frequency noise and leave longer period trends, but depending on what you're trying to find, I'd be a little wary of inventing data that doesn't exist.